# Скачать файл, не сохраняя его на диске

Tags: asp.net, c#

Добрый день.

Проект написан на ASP.NET 4. Есть форма http://localhost.....Web.aspx?Page=m8. На форме расположена кнопка, которая вызывает функцию и получает, из базы, текст хмл (большой string).

Как из стринга сделать файл, не сохраняя его нигде, не указывая никаких путей, и просто скачать его, как качаются любые файлы из Интернета?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден. Спасибо гуглу и коллегам.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[text.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(text.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".xml");
Response.End();
```